# What to do if a state and federal refund is denied direct deposit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, income-tax-refund

I helped my girlfriend file both her state and federal taxes this year. We 'share' a bank account, but her name is not on the account (the bank currently does not offer joint accounts, otherwise it would be). I entered my account information and submitted both, and they were both accepted.

A few days later, the money was direct deposited into my account, but then a day later it was removed, and I was told by my bank that they couldn't accept the money, as it was in my girlfriend's name.

Will the state (Ohio) and the IRS send the checks by mail, or do we need to contact them to change the account information to try and direct deposit them again?

Comment: Watch the mail at the street address listed on the return and be ready to wait a few weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not allowed to pay refunds to anyone other than the taxpayer. This is due to various tax return fraud schemes that were running around. Banks are required to enforce this.

If the direct deposit is denied, a check will be issued. In her name, obviously. What she does with it when she gets it is her business - but I believe that tax refund checks may not be just "endorsed", the bank will likely want to see *her* when you deposit it to your account, even if it is endorsed. For the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

Publication 17 *Your Income Tax* top of page 14

> If the direct deposit cannot be done, the IRS will send a check instead.

When your girlfriend gets the check, she can endorse it over to you
for deposit into your account.